# Why this is Used <?php }?>

Tags: php, html

From a database we are getting data, but my question is that after **tbody starting tag** and **before tbody ending tag**, why we are ending php in this way using `<?php }?>`
Why is it used in these lines?

```
<div class="container">

<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">CNIC</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Name</th>
        <th  scope="col" >DOB</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Address</th>
        <th  scope="col" >City</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Degree Program</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Gender</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Email</th>
        <th  scope="col" >Mobile</th>
        <th  scope="col" ></th>
        <th  scope="col" ></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php  while($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){?>
        <tr>
          <td scope="row" ><?php echo $student['cnic']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['fname'] . " ".  $student['lname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['dateofbirth']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['address']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['city']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['degree']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['gender']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $student['mobile']; ?></td>
          <td> <a class="btn btn-primary" href=<?php echo "update_student.php?u_id=".$student['u_id']; ?> >Update</a> </td>
          <td> <a class="btn btn-primary" href=<?php echo "delete_student.php?u_id=".$student['u_id']; ?> >Delete</a> </td>
        </tr>
      <?php }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Because You want to show a list data by row in a table

Comment: As you should close while loop's brackets. If you do not close it, this will give you an error

Comment: You can try also this :`<?php  while($student =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){echo'<tr><td scope="row" >'.$student['cnic'].'</td>';?>` but this is hard to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

like your code snippet, we can decide what is to be displayed in the DOM (html page).in your code the whole contents in

```
<tr>...</tr>
```

will print on the html page only till the while condition satisfies.if the while loop runs for ten times there will be ten rows in

```
<tbody>...</tbody>
```

here the while loop will continue till fetching the last record from the specified table.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php }?>
```

Is actually closing your while loop that starts at the begining:

```
<?php  while($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){?>.
```

If that would not be present, the code would throw you an error.

Loops in PHP (should) start and end with curly brackets. So at the begining you have something like:

```
for($i; $i< 10, $i++) {
```

or

```
foreach($a as $b) {
```

or

```
while($someCondition){
```

And at the end always a closing curly bracket:

```
}
```

BR

Answer (score 0):

With this `<?php ..... ?>` inside html code, you are (probably) showing html code inside php file. So basically you have (for example) a HTML template in php file, hence the php opening/closing tags. So while you are tehnically in a PHP script, you are actually showing something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "Some title" ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo "Hello World" ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can, I'd suggest to use a templating engine for this, like twig.

So in your case, you are fetching result from DB, looping over it and shwoing it in HTML table.

BR

Answer (score -2):

PHP has a cool way of deciding to show content. Instead of echo'ing HTML based on a variable, you can use the PHP `<?php if (...): ?> html here <?php endif; ?>` and the HTML inside will show only if that `if` condition is met. It's the same thing here, except with a `while` instead of an `if`

Answer (score -2):

A PHP while loop works like this:

```
while($x === true){
    //execute some code
}
```

This will execute the code inside the while loop an infinite number of times, or until the `$x` variable is changed (within the loop) to equal true. The opening and closing brackets, `{` and `}` are what determine where the while loop starts and ends. In your code, PHP is printing out all of those `<tr>` and `<td>` tags until `mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)` no longer returns a result. The line `<?php }?>` just tells the program, "the loop stops here, go back to the start"